# Unexpected character ('F' (code 70)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') What does it mean?

Tags: java, rest

I am trying to access a url using rest client

My Client Code:

```
 public class ProductByListTestClient {

//  private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ProductByListTestClient http = new ProductByListTestClient();
    try {
        http.sendPost();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// HTTP POST request
private void sendPost() throws Exception {

    String url = "http://localhost:7111/product.lookup.tobuylist/rest/product/productbuylist";
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setDoOutput(true);
   // con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    String urlParameters = "{\"itemID\":F123}";

    // Send post request
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    // print result
    System.out.println(response.toString());

}
```

}

Root cause of `ServletException`:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('F' (code 70)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletInputStreamImpl@186948; line: 1, column: 12]
    at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1432)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportError(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:385)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:306)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser._handleUnexpectedValue(Utf8StreamParser.java:2084)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser.nextToken(Utf8StreamParser.java:549)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Comment: Could you please share the JSON you are trying to parse?

Comment: you have json like: `{"test": fff}` which is not allowed - only booleans and numbers can have no commas

Comment: `String urlParameters = "{\"itemID\":\"F123\"}";` as @maxpovver said

Comment: my json object need to add in url : "{\"itemID\":F123}"

Comment: I have modified my data in JSON format. Now its working

Answer (score 1):

This is because of sending wrong JSON format on URL using client.
Just check your JSON data which you are trying to send over URL. If you get this kind of exception "Unexpected character ('F' (code 70)): expected a valid value".
Then You just make sure that data is in correct JSON format !